# Maximum number of umbrellas that can be added in a one kilometer beach?

Tags: puzzle, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose we have a beach of length $1-$km. Suppose one Day $0$, the beach is empty.

One day $1$, a family comes and puts their umbrella at some point in the beach. **This point is fixed forever and cannot be moved**.

On day $2$, a new family comes and puts their umbrella in a new coordinate. **This umbrella is now fixed forever**. However, we are guaranteed that the intervals $[0,\frac{1}{2}], [\frac{1}{2},1]$ each have $1$ umbrella; the old and the new one.

In general, on day $i$, a new family comes in and fixes a new umbrella. We're guranteed that the interval $[0,\frac{1}{i}], ..., [1-\frac{1}{i}, 1]$ all have one umbrella each.

The question is, what is the maximum day $t$ such that we cannot add a new umbrella where the $t$ sub intervals would have $1$ umbrella each?

The question answer say $18$, but I don't see how this is true?! Shouldn't we be able to keep going forever?

Comment: Can you present a way to place umbrellas with which we can keep going for ever while satisfying the interval condition?

Comment: Are the families trying to fit this pattern or is the problem claiming it always works? For example, suppose after day $2$ there is an umbrella just slightly to the left of $\frac{1}{2}$ and another just slightly to the right of $\frac{1}{2}$ so that both are contained in $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$. How can we place a third umbrella so that the condition is met?

Comment: The families are trying to fit this pattern for as long as possible

Comment: So they can agree on where to put their umbrellas from the start to keep this going as long as possible

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw Hmmm, I see. Initially I was thinking that the ending configuration is valid then i can “track back” to the beginning. But that might not be true. But still, i don’t see why 18 is particularly special here.

Comment: I have seen this problem before, and the proof is by distinguishing many many cases and brute force/exhaustion. There is nothing deep, just track which are the possible intervals for the 1st,  2nd, 3rd, etc. umbrellas after the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. round.

Comment: @Sevraes: how many is "many many"? I'd be quite surprised if the brute force/exhaustion approach can be carried out by hand without some clever work on cutting down the search space.

Comment: @Servaes Any hints on how exactly the search would be? I get its recursive back tracking but what are we recursing on?

Comment: @AspiringMat I do not know what you mean by recursive back tracking. It is a matter of repeating and elaborating the argument suggested in the comments above; e.g. if the first umbrella is placed in the interval $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]$, the second umbrella can only be placed in $[\frac{2}{3},1]$. The third can then only be placed in $[0,\frac{1}{4}]$, etc. Eventually you run out of space.

Comment: @RobArthan I meant "many many" to mean something like "too many to reasonably write down for someone else to read". It can certainly be done by hand, if you've got an afternoon to spare. With the help of a computer, this can of course be checked in no time.